# OSX: Snort: ERROR: /etc/snort/../rules/local.rules(0) Unable to open rules file "/etc/snort/../rules/local.rules": No such file or directory

Tags: linux, macos, database, postgresql, snort

I'm trying to setup and run Snort IDS on mac using this kinda tutorial:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3370709?start=0&tstart=0

OSX Yosemite (10.10.2);
PostgreSQL 9.4.1 (installed with Homebrew)
Snort: stable 2.9.7.0 (installed with Homebrew)

When I finally try to star it like this:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/snort -d -e -i en0 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Getting this:

```
Password:

Running in IDS mode

  --== Initializing Snort ==--
Initializing Output Plugins!
Initializing Preprocessors!
Initializing Plug-ins!
Parsing Rules file "/etc/snort/snort.conf"
...
ERROR: /etc/snort/../rules/local.rules(0) Unable to open rules file "/etc/snort/../rules/local.rules": No such file or directory.

Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

The rule is actually on place at `/etc/snort/rules/local.rules`

`RULE_PATH` is set in `/etc/snort/snort.conf` to `/etc/snort/rules`

So:

```
$ echo $RULE_PATH
/etc/snort/rules
```

trying this:

```
$ grep RULE_PATH /etc/snort/snort.conf

var RULE_PATH ../rules
var SO_RULE_PATH ../so_rules
var PREPROC_RULE_PATH ../preproc_rules
...
```

**Well after changing**

```
var RULE_PATH ../rules
var SO_RULE_PATH ../so_rules
var PREPROC_RULE_PATH ../preproc_rules
```

**to**

```
var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
var SO_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/so_rules
var PREPROC_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/preproc_rules
```

**Getting:**

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/snort -d -e -i en0 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
Running in IDS mode

        --== Initializing Snort ==--
Initializing Output Plugins!
Initializing Preprocessors!
Initializing Plug-ins!
Parsing Rules file "/etc/snort/snort.conf"
...
ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf(741) Unknown output plugin: "database"
Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

Line 741 in `/etc/snort/snort.conf` is:

`output database: log, postgresql, user=snort password=password dbname=snort host=localhost`

So since snort 2.9.3.0 direct database output isn't supported anymore. I should use snort's unified output. I could use Barnyard2 instead to redirect to postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this answer is composed from a dialog in the comments of the original question.*

---

**The problem with the rule directory**
From the error it's clear that somewhere (probably in `snort.conf`) there is a `..`, pointing to the wrong path. Based on the error, I'd say that `var RULE_PATH ../rules` is in the config file. You should change that either to `var RULE_PATH ./rules` or use an absolute path: `var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules`. You should do this for `SO_RULE_PATH` and `PREPROC_RULE_PATH` too. So your config now has:

```
var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
var SO_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/so_rules
var PREPROC_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/preproc_rules
```

**The problem with outputting data to a database**
Since snort 2.9.3.0, direct database output [isn't supported anymore](http://blog.snort.org/2012/07/database-output-is-dead-rip.html?m=1). You should use snort's unified output (like this" `output unified2: filename merged.log, limit 128, mpls_event_types, vlan_event_types`). You could use Barnyard2 instead to redirect to postgresql. Explaining how to set this up would go (in my opinion) too far for this answer. A basic start [can be found here](https://www.rivy.org/2013/03/installing-and-configuring-barnyard2/). A far more elaborate explanation (and specific targeted for OSX) [can be found here](http://wiki.aanval.com/wiki/Aanval:Snort,_Barnyard2,_and_Aanval_Detailed_Installation_Guide_for_OS_X).

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: /etc/snort/../rules/local.rules(0) Unable to open rules file "/etc/snort/../rules/local.rules": No such file or directory.

Fatal Error, Quitting..

I was able to solve this error by commenting the following lines:

```
#var RULE_PATH ../rules
#var SO_RULE_PATH ../so_rules
#var PREPROC_RULE_PATH ../preproc_rules


#var WHITE_LIST_PATH ../rules
#var BLACK_LIST_PATH ../rules
```

These lines refer to windows user!!